# My media queries for small screen are not stacking as they should

Tags: css, media

I am trying to get two columns to stack but it is not working. I am a beginner. The media queries I have in my CSS is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
```

and the css content is

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    html, body, main {font-size: 0.88em; width: 100%;}
    #firstside: {width: 100%; float:left; position: relative; margin-top: 20px; padding-left: 1%; clear: both;}
#second2 {width: 100%; float:left; margin: 2%;}
}
```

I know it is the wrong way around that I should have started with the mobile but I inherited the website and now need to get it mobile responsive. Can anyone help?

Comment: remove `:` after `#firstside`

Comment: First: those are `meta` tags in your first snippet. In your CSS, you have `:` after `#firstside` That's invalid CSS.

Comment: yes the meta tags are to show that I am aware of them, sorry for confusion. Thank you for your answer I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Put Meta Tags in  Section of you HTML document.

Fix the syntax error in your CSS selectors. The colon (:) after #firstside is causing a syntax error. Remove the colon.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    html, body, main {font-size: 0.88em; width: 100%;}
    #firstside {width: 100%; float:left; position: relative; margin-top: 20px; padding-left: 1%; clear: both;}
    #second2 {width: 100%; float:left; margin: 2%;}
}
```

Make sure you have the corresponding HTML structure with elements having IDs firstside and second2.